# Python - find whitespace or none value in multiple json files

Tags: python, json, find

I've multiple json files with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "vertrags_id": 1,
    "versicherungsnummer": "770442924",
    "vp_nummer": 581,
  },
  {
    "vertrags_id":,
    "versicherungsnummer": "7353924",
    "vp_number": 63,
  },
  {
    "vertrags_id": ,
    "versicherungsnummer": "45262924",
    "vp_number": 56,
  }
]
```

I need to iterate through the files to know in which file I have whitespaces("") or no value as value for key "vertrags_id". Then i would like to append the filename to a list. I would be optimal to know in which line the whitespace or no value was found.

I've tried the following code:

```
lv = []

path = (r"C:...")

for file_name in [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.json')]:
  with open(path + file_name) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    if data['vertrags_id'] == "" or None:
        lv.append(file_name)
```

But I get following error message:

```
 File "c:\Users\mallk\OneDrive\Desktop\Koenigswege\ProgrammingDell\Programming\postgres\test_find_value_json.py", line 16, in <module>
    if data['vertrags_id'] == "" or None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` contains your whole json file. Given the structure you've specified, it is a `list`, so you need to iterate over it.

```py
for file_name in [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.json')]:
    with open(path + file_name) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    # Close the file once we read the data
    # Iterate over the records in data
    for i, record in enumerate(data):
        if (record['vertrags_id'] == "") or (record['vertrags_id'] is None):
            lv.append("error in file {file_name}, at line {i}")
```

Notice I'm using `enumerate` to also get the record number, that you can then use as you want.

Comment: I've tried it, but I still get the error '''TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str''', any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Oh right sorry, my bad I forgot to change the name of the variable, it should be `record["vertrags_id"]`, not `data`, will edit now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
for file_name in [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.json')]:
  with open(path + file_name) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    # this will check at least one value is empty or None
    if not all([i['vertrags_id'] for i in data]):
        lv.append(file_name)
```

Comment: Clean solution for the question

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How can I know which line is affected?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your data I think you're one loop short when processing the source:

```
for d in data:
    if d['vertrags_id'] in ["", None]:
        lv.append(file_name)
```

Also, the `or` operator here doesn't work like you think it does. Instead use `in` when comparing against multiple values.